# Uploading large files (200+ mbs) from by ajax to sharepoint 2013 on premise

Tags: rest, file, sharepoint

I'm trying to upload files to a library on sharepoin 2013 on premise by Ajax. I'm using the following code:

```
function uploadFileee(file) {
// var file = element.files[0];
console.log(file);
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function (e) {

    enviar(e.target.result, file.name);
}
reader.onerror = function (e) {
    alert(e.target.error);
}
//reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);


function enviar(file, name) {

    var url = String.format(
        "{0}/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('{1}')/RootFolder/Files/Add(url='{2}', overwrite={3})",
        _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, "TreinamentoLib", name, "true");
    console.log(url);

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: file,
        processData: false,
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("sucesso");
        },
        error : function(err)
        {
            console.log("erro");
        }
    })
}
}
```

As long the file is below 200mb's, it works just fine, but bigger than that, the browser crashes.

Chunks just work on the online version of sharepoint.. cound't make it work on On Premise. 
 Already though on creating an webApi in C# to receive the chunks and group it together and upload it to the library..

Anyone have ever done something like it? does anyone have any sugestion?

Comment: Can you manually upload a file of that size to library from a browser?

Comment: yes... direct on library, yes...

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint On Premise, you can try to increase the maxRequestLength="51200" executionTimeout="999999" in the web.config file at "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\< Virtual Directory >" folder.

Or check maximum upload size for the web application : Central Admin> Application Management> Manage Web Applications> Select the desired web app and click General Settings on the ribbon.